# How to POST using HTTPclient content type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am currently developing a wp8.1 application C#, i have managed to perform a POST method in json to my api by creating a json object (bm) from textbox.texts.
here is my code below. How do i take the same textbox.text and POST them as a `content type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. whats the code for that?

```
Profile bm = new Profile();
bm.first_name = Names.Text;
bm.surname = surname.Text;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bm);

MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(json);//Text should not be empty 
await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
var content = new ByteArrayContent(messageBytes);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync("myapiurl", content).Result;
```

Answer (score 363):

```
var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Input1", "TEST2"));
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Input2", "TEST2"));
using var client = new HttpClient();
using var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) };
using var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

Or

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Input1", "TEST2");
dict.Add("Input2", "TEST2");
using var client = new HttpClient();
using var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
using var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

Comment: You can also pass a dictionary to the constructor of `FormUrlEncodedContent`, since Dictionary is an `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair`s.

Comment: Using ***await*** in Task method ?

Comment: @Kiquenet yes, in "async Task<T>" method

Comment: The StringContent technique failed: `new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` and the KeyValuePair worked!

Comment: Your KeyValuePair example worked. You have made my day!

Answer (score 70):

```
 var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 var url = "Please enter URL here"; 
 parameters.Add("key1", "value1");
 parameters.Add("key2", "value2");
             
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
 {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters)).Result;
    var token = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
               
//Get response as expected
```

Comment: How `params` became `dict`  ?

Comment: Please note that HttpClient should be reused, not be disposed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient#instancing

Comment: Not compile in c#, params is reserved keywork

Comment: @SimoneS. I changed that.

Answer (score 26):

The best solution for me is:

```
// Add key/value
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// Execute post method
using (var response = httpClient.PostAsync(path, new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict))){}
```

Comment: the FormUrlEncodedContent type already properly sets the Content-Type Header, so it does not need to be explicitly added

Answer (score 0):

Another variant to POST this content type and which does not use a dictionary would be:

```
StringContent postData = new StringContent(JSON_CONTENT, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
using (HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, postData))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use .Result instead of await

Comment: @BradFiresheets exactly, await is better.

Comment: My response was related to the content type without using a dictionary, but I understand that someone might just copy paste the code entirely without changing it. Updated the code to use await instead of .Result. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not so sure... will StringContent really automagically convert json to url encoding when you specify the encoding?