# Click a element without webbrowser

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to this forum, sorry if this has already been answered. However, I am trying to accomplish being logged into a site and click a button without using the web browser as it has its memory leak. I got no idea how to step ground on this and I am fine with using external libraries.

Comment: You could write c# code to submit form - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43158324/1554116

Comment: I need to click a element not submit the fourm, sadly the button isnt a submit form...

Comment: If it is a kind of HTTP requests, c# can simulate all of that. Probably you could start with capturing the request message, and then we can help from there.

Comment: Will do once I finish my school work.

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew like this? `HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(new HttpClientHandler()));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(baseAddress + "/api/values", "Hello, World!").Result;`

Comment: Add this code as a part of question. Adding what you have already done and where are you stuck makes it easy to understand.

Comment: You might need Fiddler to capture the HTTP request message

Comment: Im just looking for a way to click a element without using webbrowser....

Comment: You could try using Selenium with Phantom Driver or Headless Chrome Driver

Comment: @Logan Risen  You have to Post _all_ of that WebForm <input> Names and Values, including the name of the button which causes the form action. It's also possible that those names have to be URL encoded, since they might contain "weird" characters. To know the names ot those <input> elements, you have to parse the html page you get from the first response. Or, you can use any major browser with Developer Tools and see what parameters are passed when you Post the form.