# c# POST api fuss

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm building a web Api to catalog my firms bug report onto a server, and I'm having trouble with the post request that I'm doing.

As I've coded the clients they should be either sending bug reports that are formatted like this

```
public partial class JitCollect {
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Jit { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId{ get; set; }
}
```

or they could be sending strings with status reports like "OK" or whatever. My main problem is that if I send the bug reports as `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and prepending a '=' to my body like I saw online, I lose the DateTime format that NewtonSoft is expecting on the other side:

before `"2018-08-14T08:50:17.5608444+02:00"` 
after `"2018-08-14T08:50:17.5608444 02:00"`

I could hardcode something to put the '+' back but that's beside the point, I'm interested in how to properly accomplish what I'm trying to do.

if I instead try to send the data as "application/json", I always get empty data on the other side even specifying the from body attribute and the object type (which is not ideal for me because I want to be able to send plain strings as well)

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody] List < JitCollect > jsonPost)
```

any idea what is the best way to do this? here's one of the many post functions I tried to use

```
public static void postRequest(string data, string address) {
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(address);

        data = $"={data}";
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", token);

        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var result = client.PostAsync("", byteContent).Result;
        string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST using HTTPclient content type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158250/how-to-post-using-httpclient-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: I like to convert dates to an integer of some kind, preferably epoch. Human readable date formats shouldn't be a computer's burden :)

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: What do you mean by **I lose the DateTime format that NewtonSoft is expecting on the other side**? Share us related code or steps. Try use postman to send request, will this issue happen?

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with asp.net core web api, it passes the datetime correctly.

1. Controller

   ```
       [HttpPost]
   public object Post([FromBody]List<JitCollect> jsonPost)
   {
       var resul = jsonPost.FirstOrDefault().Timestamp.Value.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK");
       return new List<JitCollect>() {
           new JitCollect{ ProjectId = 1, Jit = "J1", Timestamp = DateTime.Now }
       };
   }
   ```
2. Request from postman
   [image]
3. Result From Controller

[image]