# Post data to the WebApi which its parameter is not complex object using Httpclient

Tags: c#

This is my webapi post request

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Create/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateContact(Guid id, string email, string fullName)
    {
        // code removed for brevity
    }
```

How do I post `contact` object over to the webapi? This is what I have in the client.

```
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:123");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var contact = new Contact() { Id = 12345, Email = "test@gmail.com", FullName = "John" };
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"/api/Contact/Create/{contact.Id}", contact);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
         
            }
        }
```

Comment: var contact = new Contact() { id = "12345", email = "test@gmail.com", fullName = "John" };

Comment: You can append the parameters values in URL and send them as query string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158250/how-to-post-using-httpclient-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST using HTTPclient content type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158250/how-to-post-using-httpclient-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I found the solution but not the solution of your post

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best but it works. Add more parameter at the `Route` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create/{id}/{email}/{fullName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateContact(Guid id, string email, string fullName)
{
    // code removed for brevity
}
```

and then at the httpclient

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"/api/Contact/Create/{contact.Id}/{contact.Email}/{contact.FullName}", contact);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there Use [FromBody] in your WPI.
The you can post the Contact as an object

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Create/{contact}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateContact([FromBody]Contact contact)
    {
        // code removed for brevity
    }
```

```
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:123");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var contact = new Contact() { Id = 12345, Email = "test@gmail.com", FullName = "John" };
            var contactJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(contactJson , UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"/api/Contact/Create/", stringContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
         
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah this one I know. but I want it to be querystring, not object