# C# Post Variables can't be read on Website - HttpClient PostAsync()

Tags: c#, php, httpclient, postasync

I have a web server on which I'm hosting my own api for one of my projects.
This is the php-code of the api-website:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if(strcmp($user, "username") == 0 && strcmp($password, "password") == 0) {
    ...
} else {
    die("No Permissions");
}
```

I want to send the two variables username and password with a HttpClient and the postAsync-method to this website and if the right log in data is detected, it returns the data I want.
For this I have the following code in C#:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response;
var url = "www.url.de"; //not the url I'm actually calling!
var vars = "[{\"username\":\"username\", \"password\":\"password\"}]";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   response = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(vars, Encoding.UTF8));
   Console.WriteLine(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
   if (response.IsCompleted)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
   }
}
```

But the problem is that no matter what I have tried the output from this code is, that i have no permissions. And I have changed the php-code, so that I can see which data is stored in $username and $password, but they are empty and I don't know why. I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code is expecting the data sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but your C# code is sending it as JSON.

As mentioned in the comment by M. Eriksson, you either need to change your PHP to accept JSON, or change your C# to send as form data.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43158324) shows how to use HTTPClient to send data like that.

Here's my modification of your code based on the above code (I did test it):

```
public static async Task DoSomething()
{
    string url = "http://httpbin.org/post"; //not the url I'm actually calling!
    Dictionary<string, string> postData = new();
    postData["username"] = "username";
    postData["password"] = "password";

    using HttpClient client = new();
    
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new("application/json"));

    HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. I was using `application/json` as well.