# Consuming Rest API with C# and HttpClient

Tags: c#, paypal, dotnet-httpclient

My code used to work fine which is

```
var verificationRequest2 = WebRequest.Create(AbstractPricing.PaypalWebAddress);
verificationRequest2.Method = "POST";
verificationRequest2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + ipnContext.RequestBody;
verificationRequest2.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(verificationRequest2.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
{
    writer.Write(strRequest);
}

using (var reader = new StreamReader(verificationRequest2.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    ipnContext.Verification = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The issue is, `WebClient` is obsolete and I need to convert this to `HttpClient`

I am unsure how to convert this to `HttpClient`... I have *tried*

```
var verificationRequest = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(strRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
var response= verificationRequest.PostAsync(AbstractPricing.PaypalWebAddress, content);
//help here please
```

I don't know how to do that last bit - how do I get the verification using `HttpClient`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST using HTTPclient content type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158250/how-to-post-using-httpclient-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the request in the very same fashion, as the webclient

```cs
class AbstractPricing {
  // Replace this with the actual PayPal web address
  public static string PaypalWebAddress {
    get;
  } = "https://www.example.com/paypal-endpoint";
}

class IpnContext {
  public string RequestBody {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Verification {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

// Actual code here, previous code just for testing
var paypalWebAddress = AbstractPricing.PaypalWebAddress;
var strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + ipnContext.RequestBody;

using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    // Create the HTTP content with the correct content type
    var content = new StringContent(strRequest, Encoding.ASCII, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Make the POST request
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(paypalWebAddress, content);

    // Check if the request was successful
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Read the response content
        ipnContext.Verification = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the error, e.g., log or throw an exception
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
    }

    // do something with ipnContext here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Sadly, in production, this code throws an InvalidOperationException: Misused header name. 'Content-Type'

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions see my code, i've updated it